# "Eclipse for PHP Developers" highlight color

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I've just installed Eclipse for PHP Developers and for the most part it works fine, but I seem to have a problem with the highlighter:

If you hold control and then roll-over a method, eclipse shows a pop-up of the first few lines of source of the method (That's obviously not as useful as JavaDoc, but whatever). The problem is that the background of this popup is black and I can't seem to figure out which preference to set to change this.

Bonus points, BTW, if you can tell me how to adjust the PHP Eclipse colors.

Comment: what pops up? are you talking about code coloring?

Comment: @markus Sorry, I suppose that that phrase was ambiguous, in the phrase "it pops up" "it" refers to eclipse and "pops-up" means, "Displays a small sub-window containing".

Comment: @markus This is something which would be immediately obvious if someone were using that feature.

Comment: No, it's not. I used Aptana and Eclipse for many years and am now using Zend Studio. I still don't get what exactly you're referring too because I don't see the connection between syntax highlighting and the pop-up. The pop-up is not connected to syntax highlighting. In any way, do you know the Eclipse plugin called eclipse color themes?

Comment: @markus -- Apparently, there is good reason that you've never seen this issue: it is an Ubuntu + Eclipse bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug which actually has to do with Ubuntu as well as Eclipse: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/540332

I've not gotten it to work locally yet, but this is a good head start.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  System -> Preferences -> Appearance Preferences -> Background tab -> Change color next to "Solid color" to light yellow worked great for me.  Just needed to restart Eclipse / Zend Studio.  On Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

In the Eclipse Preferences, select PHP -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring to change the colors.

By the way... some people say Netbeans is much better for PHP development currently.

Comment: Netbeans is *far* superior for PHP, but I use Eclipse more and I don't like Oracle.